# Hilfe White Rochade!

Tags: chess

It’s Black to move. What must Black do in order to help White castle queenside in just 11 moves?

[image]

Comment: It seems like there are quite a lot of ways to do this. Is there some extra clever thing going on here that no one has spotted yet?

Comment: "In just 11 moves" does indeed narrow it down further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work

> 1. -, Kg1 
>  2. h5, Bg2 
>  3. h6, Bf1 
>  4. h4, Be2 
>  5. h5, Bd1 
>  6. h3, Be3 
>  7. h4, Rc1 
>  8. a5, Rc4 
>  9. a6, Bb3 
>  10. axb3, b2=N 
>  11. bxc4, Nd2 
>  12. O-O-O, -

Comment: A neater approach, I think, than mine. Mine was a bit "brute force". Interesting that it's the same length.

Comment: Thanks, but you showed there isn't a unique solution. :)

Answer (score 4):

Here's an answer. It's 11 moves by black and by white. Same length as @Jens:

> 1... Kg1 2. e5 Bg2 3. h5 Bxh3 4. h6 Bd7 5. e6 Kg2 6. exd7 Kg1 7. d8=Q Kg2 8. Qd1 Kg1 9. Qxc1 Kg2 10. Qxb1 Kg1 11. Qxb2 Kh1 12. O-O-O#
>
>  [image: solution gif]

Comment: That seems to be only $11$ moves for white, like my solution?

Comment: Oh, yes. I can't count. LOL. Yes, so the same length as your solution! Although a totally different approach.

Answer (score 3):

One way is:

> 1... Kg1
>  2. d5 Bg2
>  3. h5 Bf1
>  4. d6 Be2
>  5. h6 Bd1
>  6. h4 Be3
>  7. h5 Bb6
>  8. h3 Bc7
>  9. dxc7 d6
>  10. c8=Q d5
>  11. Qa6 d4
>  12. Qxa3 d3
>  13. Qxb2 Rxb2
>  14. a3 Bb3
>  15. a4 Bg8
>  16. O-O-O

Answer (score 0):

After

> 1. ... Kxh2 White has six pawn moves before they have to move their King. Black can then play Bg2-f1-d3-g6 (somewhere in the line, White can play e5) so that White can play hxg6 and promote their pawn.

From there, I believe Black can essentially waste their turns playing Kh1-h2/g1 ad infinitum while White cleans up the left side of the board and eventually plays O-O-O.